# How to fix Binding TextBlock in WPF MVVM?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, mvvm, binding

You see my XAML code at the bottom; when I debug it in the runtime, I see nothing in two TextBlocks of the StackPanel of my window, whereas there is some data in the binding TextBlocks when it is running! 
Why can I see nothing in those TextBlocks?

```
<Grid Name="SchoolGridView"
      AutomationProperties.AutomationId="SchoolGridView"
      AutomationProperties.Name="School Group" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto"  x:Name="List" 
     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding 
     PeopleList}" SelectionMode="Single">

           ...
    </ListView>
    <StackPanel Background="LightGray" Height="60" 
       Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1" 
       Visibility="{Binding 
       IsDetailVisible,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="320">
                <TextBlock  Height="20" Text="asaasdasd"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock  Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Background="Yellow" Text="{Binding DataContext.FullName, 
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBlock  Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           Background="Yellow" Text="{Binding 
           DataContext.RowSelectedItem, 
             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button  Content="DELETE" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         Width="auto"  Height="50" Margin="3" Command=" 
             {Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, ElementName=List}" 
             CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, 
             ElementName=List}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
       </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
   </Window>
```

Comment: The `TextBlock` with the text "asaasdasd" is not data-bound. Do you see it?

Comment: yes, I see it; I intentionally put it to test it, but I am struggling with other ones which are data-bounded.

Comment: More code would be really helpful, how you're binding the ViewModel to View in particular.

Answer (score 0):

You must fill DataContext

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApplication.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApplication"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
```

Or set it in Code

```
 DataContext = new ViewModel();
```